# Scala: Find max element of a sub list

Tags: scala

I need to write a function that takes a `List[Int]`, start index and end index and returns the max element within that range. I have a working recursive solution but I was wondering if its possible to do it using a built-in function in the Scala collection library.

Additional criteria are:

1) O(N) run time
2) No intermediate structure creation
3) No mutable data structures

```
def sum(input:List[Int],startIndex:Int,endIndex:Int): Int = ???
```

Comment: Yeah, if only the Scala API came with a `max` function on `List`... Oh! Wait!

Comment: I am aware of the max function on the list. It doest work on sublist

Comment: Yeah, if only you could `slice` first, or create a `view`. Literally everything you're asking for is on the `List` API page. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily possible with Scala's views:

```
def subListMax[A](list: List[A], start: Int, end: Int)(implicit cmp: Ordering[A]): A =
  list.view(start, end).max
```

`view` does not create an intermediate data structure, it only provides an interface into a slice of the original one. See the [Views chapter](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html) in the documentation for the Scala collections library.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with your criteria.

There is no higher order function known to me, which works on a sublist of a list. Many just create intermediate collections.

This would be a simple `O(n)` solution, but it creates an intermediate structure.

```
input.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1).max
```

There are of course also functions, which traverse a collection and yield a value. Examples are `reduce` and `foldLeft`. The problem is that they traverse the whole collection and you can't set a start or end.

You could iterate from `startIndex` to `endIndex` and use `foldLeft` on that to get a value via indexing. An example would be:

```
(startIndex to endIndex).foldLeft(Integer.MIN_VALUE)((curmax, i) => input(i).max(curmax))
```

Here we only have an iterator, which basically behaves like a `for-loop` and produces no heavy intermediate collections. However iterating from `startIndex` to `endIndex` is `O(n)` and on each iteration we have an indexing operation (`input(i)`) that is also generally `O(n)` on `List`. So in the end, `sum` would not be `O(n)`.

This is of course only my experience with scala and maybe I am misguided.

Ah and on your 3): I'm not sure what you mean by that. Using mutable state inside the function should not be a problem at all, since it only exists to compute your result and then disappear.